# How do I trigger a event in jQuery when any item in a select box is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I want to freeze animations on a page while a select box is chosen and then restart them when the select box is released. It's easy to freeze them with `.focus()` but I'm having trouble after this.

If I use `.blur()`, this doesn't work when an item in the select box is selected as it retains focus. If I use `.change()`, this doesn't work if the item selected isn't changed. If I use `.mouseup()` this overrides the `.focus()` that was used at the beginning.

The closest I can get is to use a combination of `.blur()` and `.change()`. This catches all events except for selecting the item that was already selected. Surely there's an event for this that I can't find.

Comment: .change is better. you know all events. then why dont you try that and come if anything block you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using the click() event?

That said, you may want to consider building your own UI widget to emulate what a select box does, since it seems like the native select box isn't quite working out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to trigger on `mousedown` and `mouseup`? Would those two events work better?